# Can I print the input of a string for len not just the number of characters?

Tags: python, string-length

I'm trying to find find the longest string entered then print it as the output value. The program stops running when an 'a' has been entered then returns the longest string entered not just the numbers of characters in the string. Can the length function do this?

```py
def longest_str(words):
    words = len(words)
    return words

true = 1
while true: # start loop
    words = str(input("Enter a string: "))
    words = words.lower()

    if words.startswith('a'): #comparing if starts with a or A
        print(f"The longest string was: {longest_str(words)}") # printing output 
        break #stop once reached a
    else:
        continue # continue to loop through, no a was found.
```

Comment: You will have to save the entered strings (or at least the longest one) if you want to print it out later.

Comment: You don't keep any information on old strings and you do 0 comparisons to check if new one is longer. Your code, as is will just print first string that starts with "a" and stop the loop.
Also, function len(str) gives you length in characters, not words.

Comment: I think many things in this code don't do what you think they do. The name `longest_str` sounds like it should return the longest of several strings, but in this code you are just passing it a single string and it returns the length of that string.

Comment: `true = 1` don't do this, Python already has `True`, so you can just do `while True:`

Comment: it looks like you want `words` to be a list of words instead of a single string. also the return value of `input` is already a string, so you don't need to wrap it in `str(...)`

Comment: you can convert the string `words` into a list of individual word strings using `words.split(" ")` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: thanks @JanWilamowski what's the best way to do this?

Comment: thanks @matszwecja, looks like I'll need to add some if/else statements in the function :)

Comment: thank you @Anentropic, I'm not sure why but when I leave out the true = 1, it returns "NameError: name 'true' is not defined" so I'm not sure what to do there. Thanks for the tip on converting to a list, will this add up all the words then print the longest string? or just the longest word in that string? sorry I'm really new to this

Comment: @DanielConnors11 bool values are `True` and `False`, not `true` and `false`

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do but you have several mistakes

```
while true: # start loop
    words = str(input("Enter a string: "))
    words = words.lower()
```

This will read only one word at the time.
So, your if will be executed only if you enter a word starting with 'a'.

This will solve your problem

```
def longest():
    maxLength = 0
    longestWord = ''
    while(True):
        word = str(input("Enter a string: "))
        word = word.lower()
        if word == 'a':
            print(f"The longest string was: {longestWord}")
            break
        if len(word) > maxLength:
            maxLength = len(word)
            longestWord = word
```

Take a look at the differences
We check if the word entered is 'a', then print the longest string and stop.
If not, we check if the new word is longer than what we previously had (initialy nothing).If the new word is longer, we retain it to be able to print it.
Just call this in the main function.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! where do you recommend learning this stuff? any particular YouTube Channel? I'm struggling to make sense of it all

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string itself you could just do it like this:

```
longest_string = ''

while True:
    word = input("Enter a string: ").lower()
    if word == 'a': break
    if len(word) > len(longest_string):
        longest_string = word
    
print("The longest string was: " + longest_string)
```

Keep in mind, this will make ALL words lowercase, if you dont want that you have to remove the .lower()

Comment: Thank you for your help, that makes sense :)